# loop with text and repetitive actions

Tags: vba, excel, loops

Say I have two columns. **A** is filled with letters, **B** with numbers:

```
   A  B
1  a  1
2  b  2
3  c  3
4     4
```

The result I want to get in **D** and **E**:

```
   A  B  D  E
1  a  1  a  1
2  b  2  a  2
3  c  3  a  3 
4     4  a  4
5        b  1
6        b  2
7        b  3
8        b  4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub Test()
    Dim a, b, i, j

    i = 1: j = 1
    For Each a In Range("A1:A3")
        For Each b In Range("B1:B4")
            Range("D" & i).Value = a
            Range("E" & j).Value = b
            j = j + 1
            i = i + 1
        Next b
    Next a
End Sub
```

Comment: That would work but the value in a or b could change, so do the arrays. Thanks!!

Comment: in my code, a and b are variables not really "a" and "b" ... you can use this code with any other alphabets :)

Comment: And i want to continue for "c" but in reality for a, b or c I have about 100 possible entries I just  made it simple for the example and that s the same with the numbers I have about 200 of them. My database is huge

Comment: This code would continue for c as well ... but if you want to extend it to 200 , then perhaps you need to change the range ... the algo would be pretty much the same

Comment: If you have 100 entries in Column A then change `Range("A1:A3")` to `Range("A1:A100")` ... would work

Comment: How do I take out if in my array there are blanks?

Comment: Put a `If` condition to skip blanks

Comment: Fair enough! Long day... Thanks again for everything that was very helpful